# I'm looking for an lrc files editor

Tags: editor

I use lrc files throw the "OSD lyrics" program which allows to display lyrics stored in the *.lrc files.
For those who don't know, lrc files contain time tags which allow to display the lyrics synchronised with the current played song.
It's a pain to create lrc file with a simple text editor. So I'm wondering if anyone knows a program to edit the time tags in the lrc files?
Thanks

P.S. Could anyone with enough reputation create and add the lrc tag to this post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on the web got me this list of editors for lrc-files.

- If you have KDE this might be interesting for you: [Lrceditor-Amarok](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Lrceditor-Amarok?content=58164)
- This one is written entirely in python: [lrcShow-X](https://launchpad.net/lrcshow-x)

Hope one of them meets your needs.

Comment: I had not used lrcShow-X since a while. I am satisfied to see that it was improved and now it contains a real lrc editor. Thank you for having made me rediscover this application.

Answer (score 1):

There's an emacs mode for that: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LyricMode

Answer (score 0):

In case you or other people want to try a flexible way to sync your audio file with lyrics, you can use this online [LRC Maker](https://www.megalobiz.com/lrc/maker) that does it perfectly line by line using LRC Simple Format.

Advantages :

- User can click on Time Tags directly to update time while the music time is progressing.
- User can click on any Lyrics Line and the music current time will seek to that time, this allow the User to correct the next Line that he might missed or incorrectly sychronized.
- It plays multiple music format and stream them locally with 0 MB of traffic.
- LRC text is saved online, you and other Users can grab them later on, and you can edit them as you wish.

Disadvantages :

- No Enhanced Format (Word by Word, Karaoke style) supported yet. But this is from a progressive website and ELRC will be supported soon.

Answer (score 0):

I use vim connected to vlc over telnet to edit and synchronize timestamp in lrc and srt files. Using on windows7 over a decade, should work on unix.

https://github.com/moshahmed/vim/tree/master/mvim

```
Here is how to use vlc.vim in vim

vlc.vim sends keyboard commands via perl script,
vlc.pl talks to vlc over telnet port.

  $ vlc > tools > prefs > show settings all >
      > main interface > Enable telnet checkbox 
      > RC > enable RC (Remote Control)
    Tcp-command-Input=[localhost:2150]  
      and vlc.pl will open this socket.
    check [donot_open console]
. VIM Setup:
  $ vim your.lrc  # assuming you have your.mp3 in the same dir
    :so vlc.vim

. Press [F5] on this line to play the audio in vlc from the timestamp:
  [0:33.10]  your.mp3

+------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| 4. Vim audio controls:       | 5. Vim lyric synchronize keys:         |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| [F12] Start vlc on [cfile]   | [F9]  Get filename:time into/from vlc. |
| [F2] Play                    | [F10] Get file from vlc into cline.    |
| [F3] Stop                    | [F11] Get Time from vlc into cline.    |
| [F4] Pause toggle            | [F1]  This help                        |
| [F5] Play [cfile][timestamp] |                                        |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Feel free to fix above script